# Libraries for embedding Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

Embedding Jetty webserver into a Java application is supposedly easy; examples abound.

No examples indicate the Jetty libraries that must be imported.

I have downloaded the Jetty distribution package... it has 36 jar files.

Where can I find a step-by-step example of exactly must be accomplished to embed Jetty in an application?

Comment: ijetty is available as well for running jetty on android devices - http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/01/i-jetty-3-1-released/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty), libraries for embedding Jetty 6:

```
servlet-api-2.5-6.x.jar
jetty-util-6.x.jar
jetty-6.x.jar
```

For JSP you'll need additional jars.

For Jetty 8, try:

```
jetty-continuation-8.*.jar
jetty-http-8.*.jar
jetty-io-8.*.jar
jetty-server-8.*.jar
jetty-util-8.*.jar
servlet-api-3.0.jar
```

See also: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld

Comment: Will these files be enough to do an HTTP Request from another android device over the same local network using HTTP VERBS like "GET/POST/PUT etc"?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this if anyone else wants to know follow the link.

http://codersapprentice.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-integrate-jetty-server-in-my.html